# How can I use klaw with async/await?

Tags: node.js, async-await

I'm trying to get a list of all Java files within a directory, recursively. I'm trying to use [Klaw](https://www.npmjs.com/package/klaw), but I can't seem to get it to work with `async/await`:

```
const files: string[] = [];
await klaw(myDir, { 
    filter: (item: any) => { return path.extname(item.path) === ".java"; }
}).on("data", (item) => { files.push(item.path); });

if (!files.length)
    console.log("Directory contains no java files");
```

However, I hit the bottom if statement before the filter function has finished. I'm at a loss as to how to rectify it.

Comment: `async/await` works with Promises (thenable objects) while `klaw` creates a Stream. You need to create a Promise that is resolved when the stream ends. I'm sure there is a package for that somewhere on npm.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your code is properly running inside `async` function. You could do the following

```
// this code should be inside async function to use await keyword
const run = async () => {
  const files: string[] = await new Promise<string[]>((resolve, reject) => {
    const files: string[] = [];
    klaw(myDir, {
      filter: (item: any) => {
        return path.extname(item.path) === ".java";
      }
    })
      .on("data", item => {
        files.push(item.path);
      })
      .on("end", () => resolve(files))
      .on("error", reject);
  });

  if (!files.length) console.log("Directory contains no java files");
};
```

Or use some package that does it for you. For example [stream-to-promise](https://www.npmjs.com/package/stream-to-promise)

[Playground Link](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=const%20run%20%3D%20async%20()%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20const%20files%3A%20string%5B%5D%20%3D%20await%20new%20Promise%3Cstring%5B%5D%3E((resolve%2C%20reject)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20const%20files%3A%20string%5B%5D%20%3D%20%5B%5D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20klaw(myDir%2C%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20filter%3A%20(item%3A%20any)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20path.extname(item.path)%20%3D%3D%3D%20%22.java%22%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D)%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20.on(%22data%22%2C%20item%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20files.push(item.path)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D)%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20.on(%22end%22%2C%20()%20%3D%3E%20resolve(files))%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20.on(%22error%22%2C%20reject)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%7D)%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20if%20(!files.length)%20console.log(%22Directory%20contains%20no%20java%20files%22)%3B%0D%0A%7D%3B)

Comment: Turabanko - that's not working, tslint is telling me that promise will be of type {} and not string[].

Comment: @JohnBergqvist I'm that familiar with typescript. If you ignore the error you'll see the code is working.

Comment: No, the error is causing the code to fail to compile....

    [ts]
Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'string[]'.
  Property 'length' is missing in type '{}'.

Comment: @JohnBergqvist Try to add type declarations to inner `files` and the promise instance.

Comment: Tarabakno?

Like this?

async function validateDir(dir: string) {
  const files: string[] = new Promise<string[]>((resolve, reject) => {
    const srcFiles: string[] = [];
    klaw(dir, { filter: (item: any) => { return path.extname(item.path) === ".java"; } })
      .on("data", (item) => { srcFiles.push(item.path); })
      .on("end", () => resolve(srcFiles))
      .on("error", () => reject());
  });
  return files;
}

it's still complaining the same...

Comment: @JohnBergqvist I've added playground link. It compiles ok (up to undefined names)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182149/discussion-between-john-bergqvist-and-yury-tarabanko).